# How to understand the error in my Python program

Tags: python

[image: code for printing factors of a number]

I'm trying to code a program that prints the factors of a number, just as shown in the attached image, but the outcome is totally not what I'm expecting. (I just want the code to return factors of the specified number.) What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way of doing it?

Code:

```
number=42
factor_list=[]
for num in range(1,number+1):
    num=number/num
    if (number%num)==0:
        factor_list.append(num)
print(factor_list)
```

Output:

```
[42.0, 21.0, 14.0, 10.5, 7.0, 6.0, 5.25, 3.5, 3.0, 2.625, 2.0, 1.75, 1.5, 1.3125, 1.0]
```

Comment: Post the code in the question directly and not as pictures - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add your code to the question. Hyperlinks to images are not acceptable

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-Find-Factors-of-Number-using-Python

Comment: Thanks for adding the code as text. Would you add the console output as text too, in a separate block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to why your program does not work, let's see what is going on step by step:

```py
    number=42
    factor_list=[]
    for num in range(1,number+1):      #for num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5... 42] (Let's take 28 for example)
        num=number/num                 # num = 42 / 28; num = 1.5 now
        if (number%num)==0:            # 42 mod 1.5 == 0.0
            factor_list.append(num)    # so we add 1.5 to the list.
    print(factor_list)
```

See the problem in logic now?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the 4th line i.e `num=number/num` which produces quotients. you are trying to find modulus of `number` from those quotients that is the reason you are getting wrong answer. Here is the modified code which works.

```
number = 42
factor_list=[]
for num in range(1,number+1):
   if(number%num==0):
       factor_list.append(num)
print(factor_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the division operator / will result in a float data type even if the values either side of it are int. For integer division you should use //

Having said that, what you need here is the modulo operator.

Here's a concise (but not necessarily most efficient) way of achieving your objective:

```
def factors(n):
    return [1] + [x for x in range(2, n + 1) if n % x == 0]

print(factors(4203))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3, 9, 467, 1401, 4203]
```

**Fun fact:**

If the length of the returned list from this function is 2 then n must be a prime number. Don't go using this function to test for primes though as it would be woefully inefficient

Comment: Ah certainly, that makes sense. In the 2nd line of your code though, I see that you have defined a list- 

1. without using a variable or labeling the list
2. also used '+' sign to further add the 'for' loop (which I think is similar to list comprehension) but you have also used an 'if' condition within it, all of which helps define the list

So out of curiosity my question is- can I add multiple such conditions using the '+' sign similar to what you have done to define the list above? 

Also, if it is possible to label the list to permanently store list elements for further usage?

Comment: @CrimsonNinja Instead of printing the output from *factors(n)* just assign it to some variable. Yes, it's a list comprehension. Remember that all positive integers have a factor of 1. So that's just a constant that we can add to the output of the comprehension